# 403 error with Microsoft Graph in a Azure Web app

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

i followed this tutorial
[Tutorial: Access Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=command-line)

I can login with my organization user to the web app, but i can't use the GraphServiceClient. It always redirect me to the "signin-oidc" page with a 403 error.

Am i missing something in the tutorial? What should i check in the configurations?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What API call are you making? Have you added Graph API permissions in Azure?

Comment: I'm trying to call the "me" endpoint using the GraphServiceClient.
I've added the "user.read" permission

Comment: Can you share the whole error message? Also try to check your access token in https://jwt.ms and see if your permissions are present in it or not.

Comment: I don't have a specific error because in this line 

`var  me= await _graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync()`

the library do the challenge and authenticate against graph (i can see the redirect to login.microsoftonline.com), but then it redirect me to "/signin-oidc" with the 403 error.
I can't see the token because it's managed by the GraphServiceClient  library. There's a way i can check something more detailed?

Comment: If you wanna achieve the feature of making users sign in and then can call graph api to obain the user information, I think you can try [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph). A good sample could save much time.

Comment: I've tested in my side and the sample worked well. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fNUc.png And your 403 error means forbidden, I think you need to provide more details on what you've done to help troubleshot.

Comment: BTW, I've tested the sample in your tutorial, it's also ok for me, at least no error message. I downloaded the sample code and modify the appsettings.json, replace the domain, tenant id and client id. After that, I created an .netcore web app in app service with [enable the authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service). The only change in the newly created azure ad app is that I add a redirect url in authentication panel with the vaule `https://web_app_name.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`

Comment: I tried your sample, and if i use the same appsetting.json it works if deployed on iisexpress, but it has the same error on the azure web app , so i think there's something wrong with the settings of the azure web app.

Comment: Ok, I'll show my creating details on azure web app below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tutorial you provided, it requires the azure web app to enable easy-auth by azure ad, it also provides a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service) on how to enable it.

After creating azure web app, go to `Authentication` then click `Add identity provider`, then you need to choose microsoft as the provider and then create a new azure ad app if needed. Now we can deploy sample code into azure after doing the configuration. And as the default redirect url in the code is `/signin-oidc` so we need to add it into azure ad authentication panel-> redirect url.

[image]

==============================UPDATE============================

If you used my sample, you also need to modify the appsetting.json with the azure ad application client id and client secret. You can use the azure ad app created just now, you only need to add redirect url with `https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc` and `https://web_app_name.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`. But in this sample, you don't need to enable easy-auth for azure web app. You only need to [create a web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=netcore31&pivots=development-environment-vs) and deploy the sample code to it. I used visual studio to create and deploy. If you wanna create azure web app in azure portal, you just need to click New in azure portal->app service and complete the fields.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Using your sample and disabling the easy-auth it works, i can login to AAD and use the GraphServiceClient. I can't make work my sample, but since the result is the same, i'll go with yours. 
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your response, and in my opinion not using easy-auth is more flexible. Could you pls pick my post as the answer?